# Inject JSON file into map

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I'm building a single page web app with a Spring Boot back-end and ideally want to share a JSON file that is used by the front-end as a routing enum of sorts and by the back-end to support mapping of certain routes back to `/index.html`

Here's the JSON file:

```js
{
  "Login": "/login",
  "ForgotPassword": "/forgot-password",
  "ResetPassword": "/reset-password",
  "Profile": "/profile",
  "Configuration": "/configuration",
  "Administration": "/admin"
}
```

So far I've been doing this in Node.js as follows:

```js
for (var pathname in Path) {
    if (Path.hasOwnProperty(pathname)) {
        app.get(Path[pathname], sendIndex);
    }
}
```

Currently I have this:

```java
@Configuration
public class SpringConfigurations extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
}
```

Would there be a way of injecting the JSON file into, let's say, a `java.util.Map<String,String>` and then doing the following:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfigurations extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        pathsMap.values().forEach(path -> {
            registry.addResourceHandler(path)
                    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/index.html");
        });
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Json Jackson library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) (specifically, its [bind module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind)) is able to load and parse a Json file into a Map:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> pathsMap = (Map<String, Object>)mapper.readValue(jsonSource, Map.class);
```

if you know in advance that all values are Strings, you can define the map as `<String, String>`

`readValue()` has overloaded variants that accept Reader, Stream, pre-loadeded String, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but I already know how to do it manually. What I'm really looking for is some Spring magic to inject JSON config directly from a file (similar to the way you can automatically inject properties from a properties file).